# Error when installing matplotlib

Tags: python

I tried to install matplotlib on OS X Lion with the `pip install` command, but I get the following error:

```
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Have you installed Xcode and its command line tools? However even with this I suspect this is a complex install due to the GUI libraries which can be used  and I would use a package manager like macports or homebrew

Comment: I've installed Xcode but what do you mean with the command line tool ? I use brew as a package manager.

Comment: Xcode just installs the GUI to run C compilers from the command line you need the extra. If you use brew then install matplotlib via it as it solved the issues you are having

Comment: `brew install matplotlib` gives
`Error: No available formula for matplotlib`

Comment: If that's the question I've got gcc installed on my machine.

Comment: Macports port just works. I use macports but try to mention all package managers, looks like here they are not equal (this seems to be for python based stuff. For brew and matplotlib see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363557/matplotlib-install-failure-on-mac-osx-10-8-mountain-lion and other questions

Answer (score -2):

matplotlib is part of the python 2.7 installed with El Capitan, no need to install it.

Comment: OP is using Lion.